# How to Dispatch Action types in Struts 2

Tags: struts2, struts, struts-1

I am trying to find the replacement for `org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.types` in Struts2.

Below code snippet:

```java
if(types != null)
{
    if(types.length == forward.length)
    {
        select.add(type[0]);
    }
}
```

The `forward` is a string type object and `select` is a list type array.

Comment: Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: It is a feature of Struts 1.1 and I doesn't work with Struts2 unless you post your own implementation and explain your problem.

Comment: Hi Roman, The code snippet I have provided is the part of big code so not possible for me to post whole code but can you help me to understand how org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.types works in struts1 and is their any specific replacement for it in struts2.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [`DispatchAction.types`](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/struts/archive/trunk/struts-doc-1.1/api/org/apache/struts/actions/DispatchAction.html#types):

> `types`
> `protected java.lang.Class[] types`
> The set of argument type classes for the reflected method call. These are the same for all calls, so calculate them only once.

There's not the same thing in Struts2. You should refresh your mind to understand that struts2 works differently than struts-1.

For example you can map your actions directly to the method. You can use SMI for method call like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44676724/573032) answer

> You should place the annotation directly on the method. Because if you put it on the class the default method `execute()` is used for the mapping.

```
@ParentPackage("basePackage")
@Namespace("/")
@AllowedMethods("test")
public class UserAction {

    @Action(value = "userAction")
    public String test() {
        // your code
        rerurn Action.SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

or use wildcard mapping like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48434820/573032) answer.

> The action name is overridden if used in the same package. The action name maps to a specific method or `execute`.
>
> You can use wildcard mapping to put a method name in the action.

```
<action name="*product" class="com.DispatchAction" method="{1}">
```